# Don't pop virtual keyboard when input gets focus

Tags: android, html, angular, angular5, progressive-web-apps

I'm building an angular 5 progressive web app.

I need a way of giving an input focus without the virtual keyboard popping on mobile devices. The input will receive text via speech rec and so the keyboard just gets in the way.

I've had a play with the readonly attribute but this hides the caret and so the user doesn't know where the text will be going until it gets there.

I've also had a play with the autofocus attribute which gives an input focus without popping the keyboard but this only works when the page loads. I want to be able to move between inputs and have the keyboard not pop.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the soft keyboards are of the mobile phone's native API and the browser has no control over it without something like Cordova.

Your best bet would be using readonly and adding css to add a caret onfocus.